# Toolbar button Fragment Overlapping

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-toolbar

i am using navigation drawer template. I also add button in the toolbar. When click that button, gallery fragment should open. Actually it is opening but, when i click drawer button also, they are overlapping. Do you have any solution about it?

This is my mainactivity:

```
package com.example.shoptest
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var manager = supportFragmentManager
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setTitle("selamalr")


        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {


        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.shop -> {

                var galleryFragment = GalleryFragment()
                var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, galleryFragment, "frag")
                transaction.addToBackStack("frag")


                transaction.commit()
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


}
```

this is content main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">

    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation">
 </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my screen:

[image]

Do you have any solution about it?

Comment: why do you have frameLayout and fragment tags on your design

Comment: It is the overlap issue, maybe you have one text in your activity and one inside the fragment.. check once.
All of your fragment comes over your activity so your activity should be empty otherwise, activity text will show to all the fragments.

Comment: @unownsp i didnt add this fragment. Its comes from navigation activity drawer template.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar but my fragment gallery has an green image also. wheni click different button, my gallery fragment still exist. Because that image still appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The main issue was with the logical part and some UI changes needed to be done.
First just go into your content_main.xml file and make this change in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then go into your activity_main.xml file and add this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then finally, do the changes mainly into your MainActivity.kt file, like this ->

```
package com.example.parcaburada

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var mToolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var mDrawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var mNavController: NavController
    private lateinit var mNavigationView: NavigationView
    private lateinit var mFloatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setUpNavigation()
    }

    private fun setUpNavigation() {
        //Toolbar
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        //Toolbar

        //Navigation Drawer
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this@MainActivity, mNavController, mDrawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mNavigationView, mNavController)
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
        //Navigation Drawer

        //Floating Action button
        mFloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.text_fab_action), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(getString(R.string.text_action), null).show()
        }
        //Floating Action button
    }

    //Transition between fragments controller
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(mNavController, mDrawerLayout)
    }

    //Navigation Drawer Controller
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        menuItem.isChecked = true
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers()

        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_home)
            R.id.nav_gallery -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_gallery)
            R.id.nav_slideshow -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_slideshow)
            R.id.nav_tools -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_tools)
            R.id.nav_share -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_share)
            R.id.nav_send -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_send)
        }
        return true
    }

    //Back button
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    //Toolbar icon controller
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.shop -> navigateToFragment(R.id.nav_gallery)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    //Toolbar icon controller

    //Custom method to navigate to fragments
    private fun navigateToFragment(fragmentName: Int): Boolean {
        mNavController.navigate(fragmentName)
        return true
    }
}
```

And done. Everything will be up and running smoothly. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much. Everthing is working fine. But ı used navigation drawer template. Maybe ı shouldnt use template ı have to configure myself.

Comment: Yup, correct. Next time try it on yourself. It will be helpful for yourself as the whole code belongs to you and it will not make any fuss to understand it. Thanks for co-operation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code need to look like this, as mentioned below ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Because as you are using the navigation components, you need only fragment view to be inside the main view group. The other view will just create a distortion by overlapping your other view. So just remove it. Or else, if you want to then you can try this too ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The above code can be use if you want to shift your fragment view to other layout file. And then you can replace the fragment by call the fragment transition function to replace or add fragments over it. Use whatever suits your project.

Comment: the fragment that inside mainactivity is created with template. So i didnt create this. I cannot remove this. I deleted my frameLayout. and ı change my comment with: transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,galleryFragment,"frag")  But nothing change. How can i do that? Can you show me please?

Comment: I would like to see your code for this particular screen, if you don't mind then. Let me know if u can send me the code or not and also by which means? Or else tell me everything in detail.

Comment: https://github.com/akiilhan/ParcaBuradaTest so this is my codes. You will see the problem, when you click shopping button on the fragment. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Look at the code below that i have added. Follow that and your code will run properly. I've tested on my side, its running properly. Let me know the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You have two views `FrameLayout` & `Fragment` inside your `RelativeLayout`. Use only one container `<FrameLayout>` for your all fragments transactions.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

</FrameLayout>
```